# Проблема с navbar-fixed-bottom Bootstrap 3 в Safari iOS

Tags: css, bootstrap, safari, navigationbar

Народ подскажите пожалуйста.

На Safari iOS почему то при появлении клавиатуры появляется отступ между панелью, которая прижата книзу с помощью Bootstrap 3, и клавиатурой. Как можно решить подобную проблему, было у кого-то такое? Во всех остальных мобильных браузерах, все работает хорошо.

Красным цветом указан небольшой отступ, причем это не панель.

[image: Экранный снимок]